# Control logic editor using scripts?

Tags: scripting, game-engine, physics

I'm trying to bypass the GUI and just use the logic editor via scripts, e.g. I want an object to move +1 blender unit in the x direction each frame for a physics simulation but don't want to have to use the GUI to implement this. Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to use the logic bricks only to run the script or you don't want to use the logic bricks at all?

Comment: So I don't know how to use the script to control the objects without using logic bricks of some form (if there's an alternative method, that would be awesome) but just don't want to have to use the gui to set them up

Comment: I do not know the background of your requirement. It seams a bit strange.  If that is really an issue, you can - use another game engine or build your very own BGE from the sources that allows to skip the GUI.

Comment: So this is all background work to set up an interface between a neural network and a blender game environment in which the net controls an agent in said environment-so the network will output something like "move 3 units in the x direction" which should then be fed in as an input to a script that would then move the agent accordingly

Comment: So avoiding the GUI is no requirement at all. What you need is a way to detect incoming data (from your network) and act accordingly. As there is no sensor detecting your custom network you need to implement that by yourself. I recommend the the solution below - you can measure the communication via an always sensor connected with a Python controller. The Python controller can look for new information from your network (act like a sensor).

Answer (score 1):

Ok so based on your comment, I can tell you that you will need at least an always brick or sensor to activate the scripts. So you can't dodge that one.

Afterwards you can put them all in the same script, but it is not recommended cause of possible delays and cause you miss some of the good stuff blender has.

Comment: so I'd be forced to use the gui for at least some part of this?
:/

Comment: Yes. At least to make the script run you 'll be forced.